# How to run a PowerShell script in folder having space in its name?

Tags: powershell

Running a script in `C:\Users\Ooker\Desktop` is fine, but yields error in `C:\Users\Ooker\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

I guess it's because of `Start Menu` have space in between, but I don't know how to double click the file and make it run. There seems to have no way to bracket the path beforehand.

I can run it in CLI, and it doesn't reference itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few ways to do it.

Registry:
Edit your reg key at

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command
```

to

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -noLogo -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file "%1"
```

**or**

Shortcut: Create a shortcut with the target:

```
powershell.exe -command "& 'C:\Users\Ooker\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\MyScript.ps1'"
```

keep in mind that the opening in a notepad is a safety measure in the event you accidentally run it when it is not intended.

Comment: Is there a way to tell it to run it in a specific file, and the rest is just opening in notepad?

Comment: @Ooker - place the file in a location of your choice and create a shortcut in the start menu (eg: `powershell.exe -file 'C:\Users\Ooker\Desktop\MyScript.ps1'`). It will run the file on startup as you want and other files will act as normal.

Comment: @JamesC. it seems like the only way to do so is to create shortcut. Anyway, what is the different between `-file` flag and `-command` flag in your and Drew's version? Why should Drew's version have `&` before the path?

Comment: The `&` is a call operator and will run the script you point at it. Effectively the command will launch powershell and launch the script.